# ORA-02019: Connection description for remote database not found - on procedure call

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle12c, remote-access

A DBLINK named `@remotedblink` is provided to us to access tables from remote database and we are able to access respective tables properly.

Recently a new procedure gets created named `createTableOnGivenDates` on the remote db and provided to us to call it from our application db. So we have tried to call from our local db as below

```
set SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare
starDate DATE;
endDate DATE;

begin

select fromdate,todate into startDate,endDate from tbl_etl_tables;

createTableOnGivenDates@remotedblink(startDate,endDate);

end;
/
```

We're getting below error while calling the remote stored procedure with dblink

> ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code you posted looks OK. Was the database link recreated or renamed (so that it contains domain name, for example)? Because, that's the error you get when you use a non-existent database link. Can you - on the operating system command prompt - `tnsping remotedblink`? What's the result?

Comment: Are you doing that ad hoc test as the same user that has been able to make successful queries? Can you see the link in `all_db_links` as your current user?